# Conditional OR in the SQL Server Join – Multi-Value Parameters

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report with 4 parameters, two of which are multi-value parameters (`@material` and `@color` using `VARCHAR(MAX)` datatype in SQL Server 2008 R2). I am using a split function to return the value as a comma separated:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyView
WHERE height > 200
    AND width > 100
    AND (
        material IN (SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[MySplitFunction] (@material, ',')) OR
        color IN (SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[MySplitFunction] (@color, ','))
        )
```

(The code above would return 50 records)

The problem with this approach is that these two multi-value parameters have around of 1,500 different colors and materials and degrade the performance. Sometimes, it takes more than 40 minutes to return the results (row count in the view around 600,000).

I tried a different approach where I used a temp table and used it in the `JOIN` instead of the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT Item
INTO #TempTable
FROM [dbo].[MySplitFunction] (@material, ',')

SELECT  * 
FROM MyView 
INNER JOIN ON MyView.Item = #TempTable.Item
WHERE height > 200
    AND width > 100
    AND material IN (SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[MySplitFunction] (@material, ','))
```

(The code above would return 7 records only, but the performance is much better)
My question is how can I return the same number of records (50 rows) using the second approach by adding the other @color parameter and allowing the OR condition? So in the SSRS report, the user can multi select these two parameters and the query will return @material = values OR @color = Values.
I am open to any other approach as long as it speeds up the query and allows the OR condition for the two multi-value parameters (@material, @color).

Thanks!

Comment: It is SQL Server 2008 R2. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following might do the trick. I'm not sure I have the syntax precisely right, and it wants further testing and analysis that I can't do without the proper structures and data...

```
SELECT
 from MyVeiew
 where height > 200
  and width > 100
  and (exists (select Item
                from dbo.MySplitFunction(@material, ',')
                where Item = material)
       or exists (select Item
                   from dbo.MySplitFunction(@color, ',')
                   where Item = color)
      )
```

This performs two correlated subqueries on nested function calls. `Exists` checks are generally faster than `in` lookups in these situations. The syntax bit that worries me is the "and (exists" bit -- that's the parenthesis for the OR clause, and combined with exists it looks a bit wonky.

I think it should do what you want, but testing is definitely called for.

---

I mistrust that `or` clause. To get rid of it, try this and see what happens:

```
SELECT *  --  Better with specific columns
 from MyView
 where height > 200
  and width > 100
  and exists (select Item
                from dbo.MySplitFunction(@material, ',')
                where Item = material)
UNION select *
 from MyView
 where height > 200
  and width > 100
  and exists (select Item
                   from dbo.MySplitFunction(@color, ',')
                   where Item = color)
```

This runs and combines two queries, removing all duplicates -- pretty much the same as the OR clause would.

Next thing to check would be reviewing table sizes and checking indexes. You're filtering results on (only!) columns height, width, material, and color; if the table is huge, appropriate index would help here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It executed fine, but there a very slight performance improvement, around 39 minutes to get the results back. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I plead insufficient information. In cases like this I'd review index definitions and execution plans, and do a bunch of "make it up as I go along" querying to figure things out. (Ultimately, in may be the fact that you have that `or` clause in there. In fact... check edit above.)

Comment: Thanks Philip! The union is taking more time to execute. The problem is with split function as it is taking more than 80 of the exec time. This is a view that is based on 5 different tables. I am using the column names instead of *. Selecting all columns from the view takes less than a minutes. Once I added the split function, the exec time went up very high. Are there any tricks/tips to improve the split function in Sql & SSRS?

Comment: There are dozens (at least) of sql "split function" posted on Stack Overflow. Best advice here is look some up and compare with how you do it. Another option to try: create temp tables, use the functions to load them, and use the temp tables in the query.

Comment: Another thing, if you are using a multistatement table function, don't. Many pundits hate them, as they can destroy performance if used in complex queries. (Safe enough to use to populate temp tables, as per my prior comment.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I ended up with CLR function.